# Memory leak with "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl"

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

While I was analysing memory leaks using MAT, I found that an instance of `org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl` loaded by `<system class loader>` occupies 1,046,552 (11.32%) bytes.

Could you please let me know how can I remove this leak?

Comment: Remove all your certificates. Good luck with that. And using 1mb of memory is really a memory leak nowadays?

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut since when 1MB is not a leak? Now it's 1MB, in one hour it's 2MB.. And in few days your application crashes and your clients are mad... Don't understand your logic...

Comment: @Serhiy I don't see how a static cert store should grow in memory.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut in the case of TrustManagerImpl it might be not, but you are talking about 1BM memory leak "nowadays", giving an impression that you are talking in general..

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, Even 1MB does matter, specially when we are dealing with low end devices, MAT showing total 8.8 MB. Further, why 1MB is being occupied by 10 stances of same classes. I just want to know can I save this 1MB? By removing certificates?

Comment: On mobile devices this is definitely a issue. Are we talking about Android here? If so, please add it to the tags.